# Unable to deploy webpy application

Tags: python, apache, cgi, web-deployment

I created a web application by using webpy and I tried to deploy that application by using CGI on Apache as instructed [Here](http://webpy.org/cookbook/cgi-apache). Everything works fine on local machine but I can't open the site with different computer(on different network), how can I make it accessible to the public? is there any special configuration I need to make it accessible by everyone on internet?. Currently I configure it as instructed on the link a provide above

**NB** I want if someone type http://192.168.43.124/app/site.py on his/her web browser to be able to access my website.

192.168.43.124 is my computer ip adress and site.py is a python webpy scripts contain

```
#!C:\python27\python.exe
import web

urls = (
'/(.*)', 'index'
)
app = web.application(urls, globals())

class index:        
    def GET(self, name):
        if not name: 
            name = 'Nothing'
        return 'You want to get: ' + name + '. Is that right??'
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`192.168.43.124` is a local reserved network address as specified in https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918. If the other people aren't part of that local network, that IP will not work for them to visit. You will need an IP address that is public for public users to visit the site.

With an external IP address, the general public could visit that external IP address and use the web application as long as the correct port forwarding is configured on any routers and external traffic is allowed through any firewalls.

Searching for "what is my ip" with the machine you're running the web app on might reveal an exteranl IP address you can use. https://www.google.com/#q=what+is+my+ip however you'll still need to make sure any routers are correctly forwarding ports and that the port you're running Apache on (often 80) is accessible to the public. For example, a lot of internet service providers will block port 80 for home users.

Answer (score 1):

Anything under 192.168 is an internal network address only, and is not visible from elsewhere.

You need to find the external address of your router. You'll also need to configure your router to forward port 80 to the machine running your server.

Really, though, you should use a proper web host; something like Heroku will probably be free at the level you want.